# How to proper end a part

Tags: parts

I have downloaded [the template](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book) from latextemplates.com. It has something called parts which I would like to use. However, I dont want e.g. the references to be inside of the last defined part. How do I stop latex from putting further chapters into the last part defined? What I mean is that I want the last chapters to not be inside of any part but just a normal chapter. So that they are not figureing in the part chapter list, but only as a chapter in the table of content.

The template has a page in the beginning of each part, where it lists the chapters inside of the part. However, in the last part it adds too much. An example can be seen here:
[image: Part description with too much content]

I dont want it to list either the bibliography or the index here. Only in the table of content.

Comment: Don't worry about the `\part` business. The `\part` macro inserts a page break and generates a header, but that's it. There is no `part` environment to end. Moreover, any `\part` directives don't reset the `chapter` counter. If you look at line 349 (or so) of the template file (called `main.tex`), you'll see that a `\chapter*` directive is used to initiate the bibliography portion of the document, followed by `\section*` directives to head up the actual bibliographies (generated by `\printbibliography`).

Comment: @Mico The ownly problem is that the template has a part page, where it is listing what is included in the part. But it includes too much in the last part. You can see an example in the template pdf on page 13.

Comment: It's not easy to tell you what you should do, as you haven't presented any details about *your* document. If you really don't want the bibliography and the index to be listed under "Part II", you can always create a new, unnumbered part-level division called, say, "Back Matter", right?

Comment: @Mico Thanks for your effort. I don't have anything but the template right now.

Comment: OK, see if inserting the instructions `\part*{\hspace{3em}Back Matter}` and `\backmatter` immediately before `\chapter*{Bibliography}` in the template creates a document layout you are (more) comfortable with.

Comment: i don't know that template, but some other "templates" (document classes?) provide a `\backmatter` feature which should do appropriate things to disconnect regular chapters and parts from such things as bibliographies and indexes.  you might investigate that possibility.

Comment: @Mico When adding your code, the last chapters are just moved to the new part called Back Matter, which is visible in both the document and in the table of content.

Comment: @FireFly3000 - You write, "the last chapters are just moved to the new part called Back Matter, which is visible in both the document and in the table of content" -- Isn't that what you would want, i.e., have the two unnumbered chapters in a "part" to themselves? If that is, however, not what you want, please be specific about what it is that you *do* want. I will admit freely that I am absolutely, positively, no good at all at guessing on my own what others may or may not want to achieve.

Comment: @Mico Sorry for not beeing too clear. Let me try again. I want the chapters to be all outside of the part subject. So that the last chapters arent shown inside any parts but only in the table of content.

Comment: Then, please provide this information inside the body of your posting, rather than in a comment. That way, many more people are bound to notice it.

Comment: Will do right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you want the bibliography etc. in the main contents but not the local one (which is how I read the question, but now I'm not sure having read Mico's answer):

In `structure.tex` just before `\makeatother` add:

```
\newcommand*\mybackmatter{%
\startcontents
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{}%
\@endpart}
```

Then in `main.tex`, before the bibliography add:

```
\mybackmatter
```

[image: main ToC]

[image: local ToC]

Comment: @FireFly3000 Ah, OK. Good. I wasn't entirely clear ;).

Comment: Your interpretation of the OP's objective was much better than mine!

Comment: @Mico Maybe. Has to be a first time for everything ;).